# Android Execute method / function if minute and hour is 00.0

Tags: android

How can I improve the performance of the code below? I have created method that will execute some other Method if `Minute` and `Second` of hour is 0, but I am still using looping and that is lagging my phone up to 30% mem usage, is there any suggestion to do that ?

this is my code

```
        try {
            do {
                if ((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0) && (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND) == 0)){
                    UtilitiesService.InitLoggingService(getApplicationContext());
                    blnPerfect = true;
                    //return null;
                    break;
                    //stopSelf();
                }
            } while (!blnPerfect);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply calculate how long you have to wait until the time is at the ZEROth minute and ZEROth second ... but seeing how long you need to wait, converting to milliseconds, an sleeping for that long?

Also, you should do this "event" timing in an asynchronous task/thread.

Comment: Actually i didnt use sleep, im looping until minute and second is 0..
i have tried that solution but that freeze my ui for a moment.. but i will try with service to calculate that

Comment: OH .. you should be doing this in a asynchronous task then. You don't want to monopolize the CPU doing nothing for 59 minutes and 59 seconds out of every hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the time to 0,0 and Start a Single Shot thread

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(new Callable() {

public Void call() {
  doSomething();
  return null;
}

}, X, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```